# Ordem de Eventos Listeners

Tags: java, javafx, listener

Tenho um tableView com um listener ao selecionar uma nova linha do table view, e tenho um textfield que recebe um valor de uma das colunas do tableView;

O textfield tem um listenter ao perder o foco do campo ele atualiza o valor da linha selecionada no tableview;

O problema ocorre quando eu altero o valor do textfield e seleciono uma nova linha que o evento de selecionar a nova linha sobrepoe o listener do campo texto;

Como eu poderia definir que o evento de perder o foco do textfield sempre será executado antes do listener do tableView?

Evento que controla o foco do campo texto, ao sair do campo ele altera os valores no tableView:

```
txtValorVenda.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue,
            Boolean newPropertyValue) {

        if (!newPropertyValue) {
            if (!btnInsert.isPressed() && !btnClose.isPressed() && !btnCancel.isPressed()){

                tbViewPrecosEmp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setVlrVendaVarejo(Util.decimalBRtoBigDecimal(2,txtValorVenda.getText()));
                tbViewPrecosEmp.refresh();


            }
        }
    }
});
```

Evento que controla a seleção de um item no tableView. Quando uma linha é selecionada, carrega os valores do tableView nos textfields correspondentes:

```
tbViewPrecosEmp.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection != null) {
        // CARREGA OS DADOS DA LINHA SELECIONADA OBJETO INSTANCIADO
            txtCusto.setText(tbViewPrecosEmp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getVlrCusto().toString());
            txtMargem.setText(tbViewPrecosEmp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getMargemLucroVarejo().toString());
            txtValorVenda.setText(tbViewPrecosEmp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getVlrVendaVarejo().toString());
    }
});
```

O problema é quando o usuário preenche um novo valor no textField, e clica em uma nova seleção no tableView com isso o evento do tableview executa primeiro que o do foco perdido do campo texto.

Comment: Pode adicionar os trechos correspondentes a ambos os eventos?

Comment: Add o trecho do código

Comment: Add o trecho, alguem tem alguma idéia de como resolver ?